# Winforms datagrid get edit text

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I hava a datagridview where users can enter some text. When the user is done with his task he will hit the save button and the values need to be written to the database.
Now I need to validate these the inputed text, I want to do it everytime the Cellleave is triggerd.

```
        private void TruckGridview_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (TruckGridview.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            TruckGridview[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Empty;
            String value = ((DataGridViewCell)sender).Value.ToString();
            String column = TruckGridview.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.ToString();
```

The value is the text what the user has entered, I have collected on above stated way or like: `TruckGridview.SelectedCells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();` 
But everytime I get an empty string returned, what do I do wrong?

Comment: Is this a data-bound grid? Do the `CellValidating`/`CellValidated` events fire? It may be that the cell is still in edit mode, but I cannot specifically remember any quirks with cell editing.

Comment: Nop, I just fired it manual and it works like a charm, thanks :-)